# Get element from latest append() call

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you use append() to insert a new DOM node, is it possible to move the chain context to the new element?

This sample code illustrates the subject:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){
    $("<div></div>")
        .appendTo("body")
        .append("<span>Click me</span>")
        .click(function(){
            alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
        });
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This code attachs an onclick handler to the `<div>`, but I want it in the new `<span>`.

## Edit: clarification

I suppose I was thinking about a direct function such as `add()` or `andSelf()` that doesn't break the chain flow so much `<:-)`

## Edit: solution summary

For the records: there doesn't seem to be a native `findAppended()` function. These are some of the alternatives:

**Alter creation flow:**

```
$("<span>Click me</span>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .wrap("<div></div>")
    .click(function(){
        alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
    });
```

**Store the new element in a variable:**

```
var span = $("<span>Click me</span>")
    .click(function(){
        alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
    });
$("<div></div>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .append(span);
```

**Start a new subchain:**

```
$("<div></div>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .append(
        $("<span>Click me</span>")
        .click(function(){
            alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
        })
    );
```

**Find the new element after creating it:**

```
$("<div></div>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .append("<span>Click me</span>")
    .find("span:last")
    .click(function(){
        alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
    })
    .end(); // Not necessary here, used to illustrate how to continue the chain
```

Note: code not tested.

Comment: lol, look what you did - you've exposed the 5 trillion ways to do the same thing in jquery, hahahaha

Comment: @Dan Heberden: You are right :)

Comment: made some edits to my answer re: your clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be better to break that up a bit, but you need to start with the element or find it. So you could either:

```
 $("<div></div>")
        .appendTo("body")
        .append("<span>Click me</span>")
        .find('span')
        .click(function(){
            alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
        });
```

or

```
$('<span>Click me</span>')
     .appendTo("body")
     .wrap('<div />')
     .click(function(){
                alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
            });
```

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Edit: regarding OP edit

Keep in mind [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) (http://api.jquery.com/add/) already exists and does what the name implies. Also, something like

```
var $span = $('<span>click me</span>').click( 
                 function() {
                     alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
                 });
$('<div></div>').append($span).appendTo('body');
```

will ultimately make your code more manageable and readable

jQuery already has classifying methods to filter and traverse the dom. In your case of the DOM, you could easily use [.find('span')](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get to the element - or [.children('span')](http://api.jquery.com/children/) - use of good selectors and overall site architecture is important here.

Also, the [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) function is pretty bad-ass:

```
$('ul').append('<li>test</li><li>test2</li>') // add two li elements
    .children().eq(0).css('background-color', '#ff0000') // change the background of the first child
    .end().css('margin-left', '20px'); //revert to the original data-set (the ul) and change its margin
```

Comment: `add()` alters the set of matched elements, not the DOM, so I'd still need to use any of the other methods (alter creation flow, storage element in a variable, start new subchain or find element after creation). Anyway, I'm accepting this answer because it appears that no native function exists and you provide a good oversight of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, by redesigning object creation flow a bit.
So, create span, configure it, to handle click, and then append it to body.
This is possible, thanks to fluent interfaces of jquery.

```
$(function(){
$("<div></div>")
    .appendTo("body")
    .append(
    $("<span/>")
        .text("Click me")
        .click(function(){
            alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
        }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $("<div></div>")
       .appendTo("body")
       .append($("<span>Click me</span>").click(function(){
           alert("Clicked on <" + this.tagName + ">, <SPAN> expected");
       }));        
});​
```